# ReactJS: How to export variables from useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Earlier, data in the json format was stored in the data.js file, now it was necessary to load them from the server. I would not want to change the logic of the file into which these data variables are imported. How can I correctly export these two variables to product.js file? 
Thanx a looot! [![enter image description here][1]][1]

links and screen:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from'axios'
function Product() {
  const [storeProducts, setStoreProducts] = useState({ hits: [] });
  const [detailProduct, setDetailProduct] = useState({ hits: [] });
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDataProducts = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'https:/api/v1/products/',
      );
      setStoreProducts(result.data)
      console.log(result.data);
    };
    fetchDataProducts();
      }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDataProduct= async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'https://api/v1/products/:id',
      );
      setDetailProduct(result.data);
    };
    fetchDataProduct();
      }, []);
}

How to export storeProducts and detailProduct?
```

for clarity, add a link
  https://jsfiddle.net/constant101/br0L4a2n/1/

https://jsfiddle.net/constant101/br0L4a2n/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man... You should take advantage of `React.createContext` for such thing. This is the only way you can use to make props. check this:

https://dev.to/nazmifeeroz/using-usecontext-and-usestate-hooks-as-a-store-mnm

You can use your fiddle like this:

```
import {ProductContext} from './somewhere';


const Component () => {

const {productState, productActions} = useContext(ProductContext);


return (<div>
    <button onClick={e => productActions.dispatch({type: 'SET_PRODUCT_DETAILS', payload: {foo: 1, bar: 2}})}>Dispatch something</button>
    {JSON.stringify(productState)}
</div>)

}
```

When using `<Component />`, remember to put it around the provider you've created for.

Comment: yeah..but is it possible to make a request in the necessary file and use the data from the variable? Like this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/constant101/br0L4a2n/2/
also add a link into main post

Comment: If you check the last lines, there's a provider in the last lines that makes the "custom hook" exportable. check Providers too

Comment: Could you tell  what looks incorrect now? thnk!
https://jsfiddle.net/constant101/xu7zdn26/2/

Comment: I just edited my answer  I think it's clear now.

Comment: Thank you for your time! last request, could you check the updated post on this topic here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978305/reactjs-how-to-correctly-pass-variables-with-fetch-results-through-context